# An error concerning initial conditions in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

The following code solves my equations correctly, but still an error is returned which I don't understand its meaning:

```
NDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma p[t] f[t], f'[t] == -c f[t] + gamma p[t] f[t], 
T'[t] == b (1 - T[t]) (1 - 0.214499/T[t]) - m (1/(1 + (r/f[t])^n)) (1 - 0.214499/T[t]),

p[0] == p0, f[0] == 0.001, T[0] == T0}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 40}] /. {gamma -> 0.552, c -> 0.004, b -> 0.093, r -> 0.798, n -> 10.862, m -> 0.870, p0 -> 0.817, T0 -> 0.850}
```

The error: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this version

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

ode1 = p'[t] == -gamma  p[t]  f[t];
ode2 = f'[t] == -c  f[t] + gamma  p[t]  f[t];
ode3 = T'[t] == b  (1 - T[t])  (1 - 0.214499/T[t]) - 
    m  (1/(1 + (r/f[t])^n))  (1 - 0.214499/T[t]);

ic = {p[0] == p0, f[0] == 0.001, T[0] == T0};

param = {gamma -> 0.552, c -> 0.004, b -> 0.093, r -> 0.798, 
   n -> 10.862, m -> 0.870, p0 -> 0.817, T0 -> 0.850};

(* now fill in the parameters into the odes *)

ode1 = ode1 /. param 
ode2 = ode2 /. param 
ode3 = ode3 /. param 
ic = ic /. param
```

Now do

```
NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 40}]
```

No errors.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks like your substitution had issues. As general rule, I like to write the ode's and ic as separate commands, and check everything looks OK before going on.

Then use these in the next call. There is no need to do everything in one command and at once. As it makes things harder to find where the error is later on.

Comment: @Anovice it looks blue on my screen I am using V 14  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6qDI.png)  make sure you start from clean kernel.

Answer (score 3):

With no errors:

```
sol = With[{p0 = 0.817, T0 = 0.850, m = 0.870, gamma = 0.552, 
c = 0.004, b = 0.093, r = 0.798, n = 10.862}, 
NDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma  p[t]  f[t], 
f'[t] == -c  f[t] + gamma  p[t]  f[t], 
T'[t] == b  (1 - T[t])  (1 - 0.214499/T[t]) - 
m  (1/(1 + (r/f[t])^n))  (1 - 0.214499/T[t]), p[0] == p0, 
f[0] == 0.001, T[0] == T0}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 40}]]; 

Plot[Evaluate[{p[t], f[t], T[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 40}, 
PlotLabels -> {"p[t]", "f[t]", "T[t]"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

*1.* I'd recommend using `ParametricNDSolve` for this. But if not,...

*2.* The error is because `NDSolve` is evaluated before the parameters are substituted. The following holds up the evaluation of `NDSolve` until after:

```
Unevaluated@
  NDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma  p[t]  f[t], 
    f'[t] == -c  f[t] + gamma  p[t]  f[t], 
    T'[t] == 
     b  (1 - T[t])  (1 - 0.214499/T[t]) - 
      m  (1/(1 + (r/f[t])^n))  (1 - 0.214499/T[t]), p[0] == p0, 
    f[0] == 0.001, T[0] == T0}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 40}] /. {gamma -> 
   0.552, c -> 0.004, b -> 0.093, r -> 0.798, n -> 10.862, m -> 0.870,
   p0 -> 0.817, T0 -> 0.850}
```

[image]